# Can i add a button in a jface table row using ITableLabelProvider?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

As I am having some 8 odd columns in my table, I dont wanna use `ColumnLabelProvider`. It will be tiresome and lengthy to add colours and all for every column using `ColumnLabelProvider`. So is there a way to add buttons in a `LabelProvider` implementing `ITableLabelProvider`?

Comment: Can you explain a little further. Add buttons? Should they be shown visually as buttons? Or do you "just" want to run code if a "button" is pressed?

Comment: No, you can't add buttons using LabelProvider.

Comment: @TonnyMadsen It would be acting as a launch button for each row. Actually each row will be having some url, on launching it will open that respected page in the rcp browser...

Comment: @greg-449 okk sir, actually now i am using TableViewerColumn levelprovider update method, after putting the label provider for the whole table. So problem should be solved...